# Debug Assertion Failed in mfc140ud.dll

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

When I am creating a new dialogue and calling DoModel on it. I am getting the following debug assertion.

The code is

```
if (m_pWatchDogDialog->WatchDogServer().CurrentUserStatus() == CServerLink::AWAY)
                {
                    CString msg("Requested user is away");
                    m_pWatchDogDialog->WatchDogServer().SendUserMessage(m_UserKey, msg);
                }
            else
            {
                AcceptFile *dlg = new AcceptFile();
                dlg->DoModal(); // error is throwing up here
            }
```

The error is as shown below

[image]

[The Assertion is at the debug point as shown in image in dlgcore.cpp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAkpI.png)

Comment: And when you clicked `Retry`, what happens?  You should have been taken to the line in the runtime library that calls the assertion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: afxwin1.inl is part of the MFC implementation, not the runtime. Other than that, yeah, obviously click *Retry*, as the assertion dialog suggests... Stop being helpless. Besides, you should be using automatic storage duration for your `AcceptFile` object. There is no reason to `new` it, unless you want to train your memory leak debugging skills. Also, don't ignore the debug output on application termination. It **is** telling you, that you are leaking memory.

Comment: As advised, I changed my code to automatic storage for my AcceptFile object but I am getting the same error again

Comment: @AjithKumar. 1: click on `Retry` which will break into the debugger at the location on the mfc library where the problem happens. Inspecting that code may give you a hint of what's going on. There is no assertion in dlgcode.cpp at the break point in your image. 2: Show us more of your code.

Comment: @AjithKumar what kind of project is it? Is this dialog inside DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that AcceptFile inherits from CDialog, probably you can prevent the debug assertion by the extending the AcceptFile constructor with calling the CDialog constuctor with a lpszTemplateName argument. For example:

```
class AcceptFile : public CDialog
{
public:
    AcceptFile(LPCTSTR lpszTemplateName, CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL)
        : CDialog(lpszTemplateName, pParentWnd)
    {
        // your code here
    }

// other stuff
};
```